# why EXPRESS+EJS template can CALL CONFIG without send it when rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm learning `node.js` with `express` and `ejs` template.  While I'm learning some code I found that they could call `config` in template without sending it as a variable when rendering.

[here](https://github.com/fengmk2/todo/) is a tiny tiny project as a "todo" program,

in its [views/layout.html](https://github.com/fengmk2/todo/blob/master/views/layout.html),
I found

```
<title><%= config.site_name %></title>
```

But in [controllers/todo.js](https://github.com/fengmk2/todo/blob/master/controllers/todo.js)

I see

```
var config = require('../config');
...
res.render('index', {todos: rows});
```

obviously it doesn't send `config` to `ejs`, though `todo.js` required `config` at first.

so why the ejs renderer can call `config` while rendering?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses [`app.helpers`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.helpers%28%29), which exposes data to the view.

Example:

```
app.helpers({foo: "bar"});
```

is equivalent to doing:

```
res.render("index", {foo: "bar"});
```

In every call to `render`.

**Edit:** There is also [`app.dynamicHelpers`](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#app.dynamichelpers%28%29), which lets you use stuff on `req` and `res` as well:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  foo: function(req, res) {
    return req.session.foo;
  }
});
```

I recommend a read-through of [the Express guide](http://expressjs.com/guide.html), it's quite short and gives you an overview of what's available in Express.